# numeric keys not working after upgrading 14.04

Tags: keyboard

I have windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 installed on my lenovo PC.
After upgrading ubuntu to 14.4,
numeric keypad (on right side on keyboard and near function keys, i.e top ) are not working .

Also tried keypad settings from settings , but nothing happened.

Please suggest what to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to `System settings` >> `Universal access` >> `Pointing and clicking`

And turn off the `Mouse Keys`.

[image]

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected the correct keyboard for your PC?

Select `System Settings`then `Text Entry` to arrive at the screen below where you can change the keyboard settings.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I see that you have now changed your question to include the fact that the text entry settings have no effect.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I already tried it , but no effect, Should i re-install the ubuntu, And, at the time of editing my question, your answer was not showing, may be i didn't refresh the screen.:-) @Graham

Comment: @amitkumar3968 The keyboard icon in the bottom right hand corner of the 'input sources to use:' screen should match your keyboard layout. If it does not, select another keyboard or allow the routine to find a match. See if that helps.